# How to declare, initialize, and increment variable in django Template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

This is what I want. I am not talking about forloop.counter.  My case is not of forloop.counter because I need to increment it conditionally.

```
<div class="row text-left">
/////some counter=0
    {% for article in article_list %}

        /////{% if counter == 4 %}
            </div>
            <div class="row text-left">
        {% endif %}

        {% if article.published %}enter code here
   /////// counter++
        {% include "aldryn_newsblog/includes/general-article.html" %}

        {% endif %}

        {% empty %}
            <p>{% trans "No items available" %}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? Why don't you exclude non-published articles from article_list in the view?

Comment: As i am new to django cms and there is no view or model in it. Can u please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no declaring of variables in a Django template.

Have you thought on only passing published articles in your `article_list`. This would avoid the conditional increasing of the counter. Your template does not output anything for unpublished articles,or does it?

If your `article_list` is a queryset in your `views.py`file you might just add `.filter(published=True)` (if not try `[article for article in article_list if article.published]` in stead if `article_list`) when creating the context for the template.

You know of the forloop counter and your if statement would read  `{% if forloop.counter0 == 4 %}`.

BTW, this is a general Django property. No DjangoCMS needed for that. See the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#for).